# Design pattern scenario's

Tags: design-patterns

I need some info on Design Patterns i.e.

In S/W designing, An architect comes across various scenario's so 
which Design pattern to apply if scenario is ....

Please let me know if there is any such tutorial or any book that explains use this patterns if scenario is ... use that if scenario is .... and so on

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Design-Patterns-Elements-Reusable-Object-Oriented/dp/0201633612

Comment: All patterns always include the context (or "scenario") in which the pattern applies.  All patterns.  Since all pattern documentation already has this information, what are you asking?  Do you have examples of patterns that lack context (or "sceanario") information?

Comment: To -->S.Lott
Being a fresher in Architecture Designing world, I was curious to know if there is some info given as when to use X or Y or Z pattern.... I need those examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_(computer_science)

Check out the "Further Reading" section.

Answer (score 1):

All books contains examples and such, but I would suggest that you *do not* look for problems for which you can apply design patterns, as that by itself is considered an "anti-pattern" and only results in over-engineered programs.

That is, apply design patterns only after careful consideration!

Comment: yup. patterns are not templates or instruction manuals. they are observations of the structure of successful systems.

Comment: Yes I agree. However fresher ( In DESIGNING ), I guess needs some theory knowledge first which he/she can apply and going fwd he/she can use that experience to build successful systems.

why do u think dude ? 
consider me a fresher in Architecture Designing world :-)

Comment: I personally read the Design Patterns book by Gamma et al. I still consider that the premium work on the subject. But I think you need to read up on agile methods as well, since that "Gang of Four" book is a bit waterfallish in its approach. Regarding agile books, I recommend the book by Jim Shore (http://jamesshore.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Web reference: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) is not.. bad?

for some instant gratification try [this](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx)

for light on the pot reading, [head first design patterns](http://books.google.com/books?id=LjJcCnNf92kC&dq=gof+design+patterns&printsec=frontcover&source=in&hl=en&ei=4356S9HuC5TkswOO8aTLCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=12&ved=0CDsQ6AEwCw). is cute and whimsical.

once that sits right you could [go to the source](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612)

Answer (score 0):

[http://www.amazon.com/First-Design-Patterns-Elisabeth-Freeman/dp/0596007124](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124)

The best, it is good and fun.